# jQuery plugin tableDnD on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, tablednd

I am using the jQuery plugin **tableDnD** successfully on some webpages containing a HTML table.

On a regular monitor, everything goes normally but tableDnD on a touchScreen device causes users who actually want to scroll to move table rows unintentionally.

If the HTML table is higher than the touchscreen viewport, the user may try to scroll by dragging swiping up. However, thereby he moves a row of the table without intending to do so.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example You may also want to check with the plugin vendor to see if they have any updates or discussion on this topic. I found this: https://github.com/isocra/TableDnD/issues/98

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe specify a `dragHandle` and only make one column draggable? Then the rest of the table would work as before and your users would be able to scroll.

Have a look at [https://github.com/isocra/TableDnD/blob/master/index.html#:~:text=%3Ch2%3E-,Identify%20rows,-%3C/h2%3E](https://github.com/isocra/TableDnD/blob/master/index.html#:%7E:text=%3Ch2%3E-,Identify%20rows,-%3C/h2%3E)

Comment: Yes, I have already done that. Only the first column of the table can be used to move using drag & drop.

But this is not a safe solution

Answer (score 0):

I placed a checkbox to activate or deactivate the sorting mode.

```
$("#enableRowSort").click(function() { // checkbox
   url = window.location.href;
   url = url + "&enableRowSort=" + $(this).prop("checked");
   window.location.href = url;
});
```

PHP Code:

```
if ( $_REQUEST["enableRowSort"] ) {
   $checked = "checked";
   $title = "Deactivate sort mode";
   $enableRowSort = true;
} else {
   $checked = "";
   $title = "Activate sort mode";
   $enableRowSort = false;
}
$checkbox = "<input type='checkbox' id='enableRowSort' name='enableRowSort' ".$checked.">";
$checkbox .= "<label for='enableRowSort' title='".$title."'> Sort using Drag & Drop</label>";

if ( $enableRowSort ) {
    $js = "<script>
    $js .= '$("table").tableDnD();'
    $js .= "</script>";
} else $js = ";

echo $checkbox;
echo $js;
```

This is a simplified version of my code. It is not tested because the real code is part of my framework.